# How to write all input types values in span on change using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-input

i have a list of input types, a combination of 
`<input type="checkbox">` and `<input type="text">`

whenever i select a checkbox, it will place its value to

```
<span name="products" id="products"></span>
```

separated by a comma.

But i don't know how to include the value of `<input type="text" />`
so whenever i input a value, it will also add its value to

```
<span name="products" id="products"></span>
```

Please help me.
My Code:

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name=selectProducts]').on('change', function() {    
    $('#products').text($('input[name=selectProducts]:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get());
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product1" value="product1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product2" value="product2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product3" value="product3" />
<!-- i want to include these input type text -->
<input type="text" name="selectProducts" id="product4" value="product4" />
<input type="text" name="selectProducts" id="product5" value="product5" />
<span name="products" id="products"></span>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
product1,product2,product3,product4,product5
```

The only working here is the checkbox. Please help me to do in the input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `type=text` inputs to jquery selector.

```
$('input[name=selectProducts]:checked, input[name=selectProducts][type=text]')
```

So your code should changed to

```
$('input[name=selectProducts]').on('change', function() {
    $('#products').text($('input[name=selectProducts]:checked, input[name=selectProducts][type=text]').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get());
});
```

```js
$('input[name=selectProducts]').on('change keyup', function() {
  $('#products').text($('input[name=selectProducts]:checked, input[name=selectProducts][type=text]').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product1" value="product1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product2" value="product2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product3" value="product3" />
<input type="text" name="selectProducts" id="product4" value="product4" />
<input type="text" name="selectProducts" id="product5" value="product5" />
<span name="products" id="products"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mohammad. I have a follow up question. Please help me. This is the link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531497/how-to-write-total-of-all-input-types-values-in-span-on-change-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code

```
$(() => {
    var prods = $("span#products");
    $("input[type='text'], input[type='checkbox']").change((el) => {
      if(!el.target.checked && el.target.type=="checkbox") return;
      else{
        prods.html(prods.html() + el.target.value);
      }
    });
});
```