# How to write sum of all input types values in span on change using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-input

Currently, i can output each of their value and display it as a series, but what i want is to sum all of their values and display its total.

This is my sample Code:

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name=selectProducts]').on('change', function() {    
    $('#products').text($('input[name=selectProducts]:checked, input[name=selectProducts][type=text]'').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get());
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product1" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product2" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product3" value="5" />
<!-- i want to include these input type text -->
<input type="text" name="selectProducts" id="product4" value="10" />
<input type="text" name="selectProducts" id="product5" value="10" />
<span name="products" id="products"></span>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
5,5,5,10,10


35  <!-- my desired output should look like this -->
```

I want to sum all of them to get the total of `35`.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) to converting jquery object to array and use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to loop through array items and sum values.

```
$('input[name=selectProducts]').on('change', function() {    
    $('#products').text(function(){
        return $('input[name=selectProducts]:checked, input[name=selectProducts][type=text]').toArray().reduce(function(tot, val) {
            return tot + parseInt(val.value);
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

```js
$('input[name=selectProducts]').on('change keyup', function() {    
  $('#products').text(function(){
    return $('input[name=selectProducts]:checked, input[name=selectProducts][type=text]').toArray().reduce(function(total, val) {
      return total + parseInt(val.value);
    }, 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product1" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product2" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product3" value="5" />
<input type="text" name="selectProducts" id="product4" value="10" />
<input type="text" name="selectProducts" id="product5" value="10" />
<span name="products" id="products"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it by setting a variable (`count` in this example) and using an `each` function instead of the map:

```js
$(function() {
  let count;
  $('input[name=selectProducts]').on('change', function() {
    count = 0;
    $('input[name=selectProducts]:checked, input[name=selectProducts][type=text]').each(function(){
      count += parseInt(this.value);
    })
    $('#products').text(count);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product1" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product2" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product3" value="5" />
<input type="text" name="selectProducts" id="product4" value="10" />
<input type="text" name="selectProducts" id="product5" value="10" />
<span name="products" id="products"></span>
```

Comment: No point to the `map` and `get` calls (if you're just looping, `map` is the wrong tool; `each` is the right one), and you're still calling `text` with the array instead of the sum.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I've simplified and updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're headed the right way other than a syntax error, but you haven't actually summed them up. `Array#reduce` is the classic tool for summing values in an array. See comments:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name=selectProducts]').on('change', function() {    
    // Get the values, turn them into numbers
    var values = $('input[name=selectProducts]:checked, input[name=selectProducts][type=text]').map(function() {
      return +this.value;
      //     ^---- coerce to number
    }).get();
    // Sum them up
    var sum = values.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
    // Show the result
    $('#products').text(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product1" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product2" value="5" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selectProducts" id="product3" value="5" />
<!-- i want to include these input type text -->
<input type="text" name="selectProducts" id="product4" value="10" />
<input type="text" name="selectProducts" id="product5" value="10" />
<span name="products" id="products"></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```